# Export HTML table to Excel with images and icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, export-to-excel

I have been trying to export my html table data to excel. I have been able to do the same through many javascript frameworks like reading `innerhtml` from the `div`.

```
var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTM], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
};
```

**The problem**

My html content has font-awesome icons as given below

```
 <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up green"></i>
```

and some html cells also has progress bars

```
<div  class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar"
                                                 style="height: 2px; position: relative; border-radius: 2px; margin-top: 7px; left: 3%;"
                                                 ng-style="{'backgroundColor':event.backgroundColor,'width' :event.timeLineWidthPercent}">
</div>
```

They are not being able to be exported. I am not able to find a way which can export data with these icons and progress bars.